# Express $n(\pi/2)^{n-1} -n(n-1)(n-2)(\pi/2)^{n-3} + ...$ as a sum

Tags: calculus

I have obtained that
$$
\mathbb{S}_n =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin(x)dx = n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-1} -n(n-1)(n-2)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-3} + n...(n-4)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-5} ...
$$
Or:
$$
\mathbb{S}_n = \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-1} -\frac{n!}{(n-3)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-3} + \frac{n!}{(n-5)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-5} ...
$$
How can I express this using $\sum$ notation. And if there is more elegant way to express this how should it be done. Thank you.

Comment: How about $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {(-1)^k \frac{{n!}}{{(n - 2k - 1)}}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right)^{n - 2k - 1} } ?
$$ Btw, I got $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{(2k + 1)!}}\frac{1}{{n + 2k + 2}}\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right)^{n + 2k + 2} } 
$$ for this integral. How did you obtain your series?

Comment: @Gary 
Using integration by parts $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin(x)dx = - \left[x^n \cos x \right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^{n-1} \cos x dx$$
Repeating the process a couple times (note that $x^k \cos x$ is always $0$ when evaluated at $0$ and $\pi/2$):
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin(x)dx = n \left( \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-1} -(n-1)(n-2) \left( \left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-3} -(n-3)(n-4)  \left( \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^{n-5} ... \right) \right) \right)
$$

Comment: @Gary Multiplying
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} x^n \sin(x)dx = n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-1} -n(n-1)(n-2)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-3} + n...(n-4)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-5} ...
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N} $, using double integration by parts, we have : \begin{aligned}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x^{n}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=\left[-x^{n}\cos{x}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+n\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x^{n-1}\cos{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ &=n\left[x^{n-1}\sin{x}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-n\left(n-1\right)\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{x^{n-2}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\ I_{n}&=n\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{n-1}-n\left(n-1\right)I_{n-2}\end{aligned}

If $ n=2p $, such that $ p\in\mathbb{N} $, then, for all $ k\leq p $, we have : \begin{aligned}I_{2k}&=2k\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k-1}-2k\left(2k-1\right)I_{2k-2}\\ \iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}I_{2k}&=\frac{2\left(-1\right)^{k}k}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k-1}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}I_{2k-2}\\ \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}I_{2k}-\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}I_{2k-2}\right)}&=2\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}k}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\left(-1\right)^{p}}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{p}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}I_{2p}-I_{0}&=2\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}k}{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}\end{aligned}

Now since, for all $ k\in\mathbb{N} $, $ \prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}{2j\left(2j-1\right)}=\left(2k\right)! $, we get : $$ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle I_{2p}=\left(-1\right)^{p}\left(2p\right)!\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{p}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(2k-1\right)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}\right)\end{array}$} $$

Now we can do the same if we suppose $ n=2p+1 $, $ p\in\mathbb{N} $, then : $$ \fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle I_{2p+1}=\left(2p+1\right)!\sum_{k=0}^{p}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{p-k}}{\left(2k\right)!}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2k}}\end{array}$} $$

Comment: Note that for $I_{2p}$ you can use $\frac{{2k}}{{(2k)!}} = \frac{1}{{(2k - 1)!}}$. From the final result you can guess that the original integral is basically the integral remainder of the Taylor series of $\sin$ or $\cos$ centered at $0$ and evaluated at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks @Gary I've just fixed it.